# Subdomain Routing Results in ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to implement a feedback section in my Laravel 5.1 app. I want the feedback implemented in a subdomain like `feedback.my.app`. I've gotten so far:

```
Route::group(['domain' => "feedback.my.app"], function() {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'FeedbackController@index'
    ]);
});
```

Now, if I head to the browser and head to the url: `feedback.my.app` I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error in the browser.

`php artisan route:list` shows that the route is setup correctly:

```
| Domain                  | Method   | URI |  Name | Action                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| feedback.my.app         | GET|HEAD | /   |       | App\Http\Controllers\FeedbackController@index
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Did you correctly setup your webserver?

Comment: @VaidasLungis I am using `homestead`. The rest of the application routes are working just fine.

Comment: Please read this article https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-and-subdomains

Comment: @CodePoet Did you setup your vhost adding ServerAlias for your subdomain? Can you post your Vhost? You should add serverAlias in your Vhost otherwise you'll get error.

Comment: @JohnRoca Yes, that was the missing piece. I added an alias for the subdomain and sanity is restored :) Please post you comment as an answer and I will give it to you.

Comment: @CodePoet Glad I could help. I just posted my answer, You can mark my answer as correct. Best, John

Comment: @CodePoet Please mark my answer as correct as it helped you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **ServerAlias** in your VHost Configuration.

Adding **ServerAlias** in your vhost configuration will fix your problem.

Here is the link for more info. [More on Name-Based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)